# How to draw a circle with dashed border in php?

Tags: php, graphics, geometry

I want to draw a circle with dashed border. imagearc function can be used for simple border. But I don't get any way for dashed border.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

here it is

```
<?php 
function dashedcircle($im, $cx, $cy, $radius, $colour, $dashsize=5) { 

   $dash=false; 
   for ($angle=0; $angle<=(180+$dashsize); $angle+=$dashsize) { 
      $x = ($radius * cos(deg2rad($angle))); 
      $y = ($radius * sin(deg2rad($angle))); 

      if ($dash) { 
         imageline($im, $cx+$px, $cy+$py, $cx+$x, $cy+$y, $colour); 
         imageline($im, $cx-$px, $cx-$py, $cx-$x, $cy-$y, $colour); 
      } 
      $dash=!$dash; 
      $px=$x; 
      $py=$y; 
   } 
} 
?>
```

---

one more way of drawing a dashed-line circle.enjoy!

```
<?php

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$im = imagecreate(100,100);

$b   = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0, 0);
$w   = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);

$style = array ($b,$b,$b,$b,$b,$w,$w,$w,$w,$w);

imagesetstyle ($im, $style);

imagearc($im,50,50,100,100,0,360,IMG_COLOR_STYLED);

imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagearc.php)

Comment: Tried the first one: `dashedcircle($im,70,80,20,$green,1);` but it only works if cx and cy are the same. http://viper-7.com/8zXkCK

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I used to do it.

```
<?php
$thick = 10;
// create a 200*200 image
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);

// Add antialias
imageantialias ($img, true);

// allocate some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);

// draw the dashed circle

for($t = 1;$t<($thick+1);$t++) {
    for($i = 0;$i<360;$i+=10) {
        imagearc($img, 100, 100, 200-($t/5), 200-($t/5),  $i, $i+5, $white);
        imagearc($img, 100, 100, 200+($t/5), 200+($t/5),  $i, $i+5, $white);
    }
}

// output image in the browser
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);

// free memory
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

Comment: I think OP already know how to draw a circle, he wants to know how to make a dashed board

Comment: By staggering the angle you create a dashed circle.  Look at the for loop which is iterating the angle.

Comment: Ok, this works fine. But I also want to anti alias and change thickness of border if possible.

Comment: I added thickness into it based on examples on the imagearc php manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagearc.php  I am not really sure about adding anti aliasing though. If I find anything I will let you know.